# Automatic transmission car shudders when stopped

Tags: automatic-transmission

I have a Mitsubishi Lancer 2003 automatic transmission car. When it is in drive mode and stationary (brakes pressed) the engine starts to vibrate.

Could anyone be able to let me know the how to fix this issue.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like one of 2 things to me:

1. The engine is fine, but the engine or transmission mountings have come loose or failed. These must be replaced every so often
2. The engine is running rough, maybe a cylinder is misfiring which is causing the engine to vibrate

First, I would get under the hood and look at the ignition system. Look for loose, damaged or oily spark plug cables, pull the spark plugs and check them. Also get a flashlight and check the motor mounts you can see (if you can see them, I have no idea with a Lancer), you may be able to tell if they are shot with a visual inspection.

Next I would read the car's OBD codes, most auto stores will do this for you for free, you can also get inexpensive USB or bluetooth readers and do it yourself. I personally use a bluetooth reader paired with an android tablet and the Torque app. If there is a cylinder misfiring the engine computer will probably throw a code telling your which one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am sure it is not the spark plugs since the knocking goes away once I shift the gear to park. So if it is something to do with the mounts does this mean that the motor creates extra force on the mounts when car is on drive mode and stationary with brakes pressed than when the car is moving or on park mode?

Comment: Make no assumptions @MichaelSchroter. When you are in park the engine is not engaged to the drivetrain, when you put it in drive engine vibrations get transferred differently.